# How do I round a number to the nearest 5 in my coffee script file?

Tags: coffeescript

I have a restaurant recommendation app, built in Rails 4.2, and using Mithril.Js. When user searches for a restaurant, I tell him how many results I found using the code below.

How do I adapt this to show him the number of results rounded up to the nearest 5 (if <10 results), and to the nearest 10 (if <100 results), and to the nearest 100 (if <1000 results)?

**RESTAURANTS.COFFEE FILE**

```
App.c.restaurants =
  controller: ->
    loadMore: ->
      loading = true
      pubsub.publish 'search', page: store[store.length-1].page+1

  view: (ctrl) ->
    head = if loading
             'Calculating...'
           else if store.length
             "About #{store[0].totals || 0} restaurants"
           else
             ''
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be done on Rails backend? You do not want to send   900 results if the frontend will only display 100 of them.

Comment: i'm just trying to fix the label/text user sees right now... so for example instead of saying 'about 38 posts' i want to simplify and say 'about 40 posts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function you could define

```
round_to_nth = (number, nth) ->
  if number % nth >= (nth/2) then parseInt(number / nth) * nth + nth else parseInt(number / nth) * nth
```

and use

```
"About #{round_to_nth(store[0].totals, 100) || 0} restaurants" # for nearest 100th

"About #{round_to_nth(store[0].totals, 5) || 0} restaurants" # for nearest 5th
```

Comment: thanks. how / where do I define this function? and how do I call it in the code above? sorry, i'm new hence the basic questions...

Comment: also how do I get it to do the other stuff in my question : round to the nearest 10 or 100, depending on how many results are shown (see question)

Comment: @hikmatyar I've updated the answer to who how you would use it. You can define this anywhere in the file except within the scope of `App.c.restaurants`. You should review [Coffeescript Functions](http://coffeescript.org/#literals)

Comment: hm, this still isn't quite working right.. when there is just 1 result, it rounds that to 0.. if its more than 10 results then the code works fine..could you pls edit your answer to amend for this issue?

Comment: @hikmatyar So you would like it to always round up?